# Does Apple expose APIs to fetch access Mac's keychain?

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext, keychain

In my sublimetext plugin I have to make a secure http call to fetch some data. For this I want to access mac's keychain to get username and password.

Keyring seems to do the job:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring#installing-and-using-python-keyring-lib

Should that be my way ahead? Or are there any native mac apis?

Answer (score 2):

There is the [`security`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html) command-line interface.  In fact, it looks like keyring just [wraps this command](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/blob/master/keyring/backends/OS_X.py) to make it more user-friendly.

You're probably looking for the `find-internet-password` subcommand.  For example, you can run

```
security find-internet-password -w -a my_account_name -s my_server_name
```

(with the appropriate substitutions for your account and server).  The first time (at least) that you run this, OS X should pop up a little window asking if it's okay.  If you click "Allow" or "Always Allow", it will output the password as a string.  So you probably want whatever scripting interface you have to store it as a variable.